# iPod Touch 1st generation upgradeability

Tags: ipod-touch, ipod

How do I restore and upgrade my iPod Touch 1st generation so I can download newer  games on it?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, you can't.

The latest iOS that the original iPod touch can run is 3.1.3 released February 2010
*Source:* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_iOS